# Every time I tried to add a new item I got an error

Tags: php, mysql

every time i tried to added a new item i get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /web/stud/u1177827/add_boat.php on line 138

can any one help me to solve it??

and here you go this is my code in php

```
<?php
$title="Register";
include("header.php");
?>
        <div id="content_wrapper">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="1000">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">

                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <section id="main_content">
                            <?php
                            session_start();
                                if(!isset($_SESSION["staff"])){
                                header("location:staff_login.php");
                                exit();

                            if(isset($_POST['boatNo'])){

                            $boatNo = $_POST['boatNo'];
                            $boatNo = strip_tags($boatNo);

                            $location = $_POST['location'];
                            $location = strip_tags($location);

                            $type = $_POST['type'];
                            $type = strip_tags($type);

                            $cabins = $_POST['cabins'];
                            $cabins = strip_tags($cabins);

                            $rent = $_POST['rent'];
                            $rent = strip_tags($rent);

                            $ownerNo = $_POST['ownerNo'];
                            $ownerNo = strip_tags($ownerNo);

                            $staffNo = $_POST['staffNo'];
                            $staffNo = strip_tags($staffNo);

                            $branchNo = $_POST['branchNo'];
                            $branchNo = strip_tags($branchNo);

                            $results = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `BoatForRent` WHERE boatNo='$boatNo' LIKE '".$_GET['boatNo']."'");
                            $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

                            if($row > 0) 
                            {
                                echo '
                                <div class="alert">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                    <strong>boat id already exists!</strong> please choose another Boat ID
                                </div>
                                ';
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                $done = mysql_query("INSERT INTO BoatForRent(boatNo, location, type, cabins, rent, ownerNo, staffNo, branchNo) VALUES ('$boatNo', '$location', '$type','$cabins','$rent','$ownerNo','$staffNo','$branchNo')");

                                if($done) { 
                                    echo '
                                    <div class="alert alert-done">
                                        A New Boat Have been Added Successful
                                    </div>
                                    ';
                                } 

                                else {
                                    echo '
                                    <div class="alert">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                        <strong>A New Boat Have been Added Unsuccessful! </strong> please try again
                                    </div>
                                    ';
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ?>

                        <p><h2>Add new boat</h2></p>
                            <TABLE>
                                <FORM action="add_boat.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <TR>
                                <TD>Boat ID</TD><TD><INPUT type=TEXT name='boatNo'>
                            </TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR><TD>Address</TD><TD><INPUT type=TEXT name='location'>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD>Boat Type</TD><TD><INPUT type=TEXT name='type'>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Number of Cabins</TD><TD><INPUT type=TEXT name='cabins'>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <tr>
                <td>Rent</td>
                <td><input type="text" name='rent' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Owner ID</td>
                <td><input type=TEXT name='ownerNo' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <TR>
                <TD>Staff ID</TD><TD><INPUT type=TEXT name='staffNo'>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
                <TD>Branch ID</TD><TD><INPUT type=TEXT name='branchNo'>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR><TD><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1">
        </TD>
        <TD><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2">
        </TD>
    </TR>
</FORM>
</TABLE>

                        </section>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `}` closing brace for this condition

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["staff"])){
```

try to close this according your requirement like

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["staff"])){
    header("location:staff_login.php");
    exit();
}
```

and where you want

try to check with `isset()` or `empty()` to avoid notices

```
$boatNo = (!empty($_POST['boatNo']) ? $_POST['boatNo'] : '');
```

Comment: thx very much
how about this error do u know how to solved?
Notice: Undefined index: boatNo in /web/stud/u1177827/add_boat.php on line 46
× boat id already exists! please choose another Boat ID

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're missing a closing brace `}` for this if block:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["staff"])){
    header("location:staff_login.php");
    exit();
} // <-- this was missing
```

The error `unexpected $end` is saying that the interpreter didn't expect to see the end of the script because it was still waiting for a closing brace.

Comment: thx very much
how about this error do u know how to solved?
Notice: Undefined index: boatNo in /web/stud/u1177827/add_boat.php on line 46
× boat id already exists! please choose another Boat ID

Comment: @RakeshSharma you edited the wrong answer. Rolled back.

Comment: @KhaledAl-sadi the undefined index error is coming from when you use `$_GET['boatNo']` on the  `mysql_query` line. That isn't right at all, even with the undefined index fixed, you can't have a WHERE clause that looks like `WHERE a = 'x' LIKE 'y'`.